# Is "me trying to do [something]" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, slang

Why are there some people saying

> Me trying to...

Should it be

> "I try to..."

Is this grammatically correct?
How should I then finish this?

Comment: Can't tell without the full context.

Comment: This is kinda like colloquial thing. Like the assignment is too long, me trying to finish that.

Comment: Never heard it in that context, but I'm really old. I could see it as a caption to a picture "Me trying to water ski".

Comment: It could also be used in a simile, such as "Me trying to water ski would be about as graceful as a hippo bungee jumping."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ACC-ing construction

(*She didn't like me singing five nights a week*)

is equally as grammatical as the POSS-ing

(*She didn't like my singing the National Anthem in Klingon*).

An ACC-ing construction can certainly be fronted as subject:

*John trying to dance is a sight best avoided.*

but tends to sound stuffy, and faintly ridiculous with a pronoun instead of a noun:

*Me / him ... trying to dance is a sight best avoided.*

....

As @deadrat says, the objective is the default case in a sentence fragment:

[This is a picture of] *Me attempting to dance*.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is really detailed. Whereas, I don't quite understand the structure of the sentence"John trying to dance is a sight best avoided." Why isn't there a "is" after John and avoid is the tense "avoided."

Comment: It's related to 'Have you ever seen John trying to dance', with 'John trying to dance' used as subject rather than object.