# Gerund without "to be" verb

Tags: verbs, sentence, gerunds

> You not loving me is my nightmare.

Is this sentence correct?
If not, would you please tell me the correct form?

Comment: There's everything, gerund, *to be* verb and all. What's not to be correct here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "me trying to do \[something\]" [as subject] grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349916/is-me-trying-to-do-something-grammatical)

Answer (score 2):

> [*You* / *your not loving me*] *is my nightmare*.

Both forms of the personal pronoun are perfectly acceptable, though the genitive (possessive) form "your" is considered slightly more formal by some speakers.

Other than that, there is no semantic difference.

Note that "not loving me" is a verb phrase serving as predicate of the bracketed subject clause.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Nitpick: "your" is a possessive not an accusative.

Comment: @Stuart F Yikes! Corrected now. Thank you for spotting my slip.

Answer (score -1):

Learners in countries where English is 2nd language, use gerunds when they often don't get the proper noun form of a verb.  They use running in place of race; loving instead of love (where 'love' functions as a noun); laughing in lieu of laughter. Sometimes it ends up being awkward when the noun form of 'give'becomes giving or gift, because both are different when used.  Gradually these learners get used to the proper noun form; I also used to do it in the beginning.

Now, coming to the use of 'ing' form in such examples as:

You raising a question makes no difference, or
Your raising a question makes no difference, the difficulty is defining the function of 'you' in the first sentence.  In the second sentence 'your' functions as  possessive adjective.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with your last sentence. "Your" is not a genitive (possessive) adjective, but a genitive **pronoun** functioning as subject of the clause "your not loving me". (Note that even in, say, "I like your house", "your" is a genitive determiner, not an adjective.

Answer (score -2):

Strictly, since a gerund functions as a noun, the noun or pronoun should be in the possessive case giving "*You**r*** not loving me is my nightmare." but "You not loving me" is what you are most likely to hear in ideomatic speech.

The reason for using the possessive is that we don't use the nominative case with true nouns which would give sentences like "You coat is red", "John house is small", "Me car is a Volvo".

Actually there are non-standard English dialects where the posessive form of the first person singular is 'me' instead of 'my' but when users of those dialects say "me car" or "me 'ouse" (the possessive 'me' is usually accompanied by dropped 'h's) they are using 'me' as a possessive.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I don't buy that "should be in the possessive case" line. From [an earlier question:](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner#comment459786_2625) *Gerund clauses have two complementizers: the normal **Acc-ing** complementizer (without **him** telling me), and the **Poss-ing** complementizer (without **his** telling me). Both are correct, both are common, but **Acc-ing is somewhat more common in practice.***

Comment: There is no complement in "You / your not loving me is my nightmare", so there can hardly be a complementizer! "You / your" is the subject and "not being there" is the predicate verb phrase.