# "I saw you doing something"

Tags: grammar, phrases, nouns, gerunds, infinitives

Apologize that I know there are many similar questions but I am still not satisfied with them so asking a new question here.

For example, there is a sentence like "I saw you doing something".

[Non-finite clause complementation of complex transitive verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114365/non-finite-clause-complementation-of-complex-transitive-verbs)

The above link's guy suggests that this form is possible for sense verbs and infinitive form is actually interchangeable with gerund form. I do understand that and it's clear.

But, how about this: "You being that kind of person harms everybody"? (Sorry I just made a sentence and it has no meaning)

More generally, I am questioning if it's possible to use

```
noun + infinitive/gerund + object
```

as a noun phrase.

It's always confusing.

Comment: This is a timely question.  I am not sure this is an answer, so it’s in ‘comment’.  You illustrate, I think, the grey border between rule-based explanation of grammatical patterns and attention to ‘usage’.  Your sentence does mean something.  A paraphrase would be something like:   “The fact that you are the kind of person you are harms everyone.”. You can criticise the the statement in all sorts of ways.  It’s not being the kind of person that does the harm:  it’s the behaviour.  And you could defend the sentence by claiming the two things are the same.  I could say “you” should be “your”.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["...his parents' dream of \*him\* achieving a Cambridge degree." What is the function of "him" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94235/his-parents-dream-of-him-achieving-a-cambridge-degree-what-is-the-funct) (This answers the 'Everybody is harmed by you/your being that kind of person' question. The related ACC-ing as subject question is answered elsewhere, and sentences involving the to-infinitive are a totally different question.)

Comment: [Is 'me trying to do something' grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349916/is-me-trying-to-do-something-grammatical/349932#349932) has 'John trying to dance is a sight best avoided.'

Comment: 'We knew [John] to be a spy' is addressed at the question you reference. 'John to be a spy was something we knew' is, however, not grammatical.

Comment: Possible  duplicate  of:
     https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/i-saw-him-crossing-vs-i-saw-him-cross

Comment: the sentence you wrote is grammatical and meaningful, and the answer to your question toward the end of your post is *yes*

Answer (score -1):

It is said that there is a small difference between

a) I saw her go home... and

b) I saw her going home...,

in that the former reflects 'go' as a regular action, and in the latter 'going' was progressing exactly (ie only) at that time.

This is not a universally accepted argument.  Still, grammarians in general say that both are not much dissimilar. I always tend to favour the first one, but it is not passivisable:

a' *She was seen go home.

b' She was seen going home.

Comment: Hello, Ram. I was just reformatting (it's not easy until you get used to ELU's quirks), but saw that 'isn't as good' should be 'isn't grammatical' (abbreviated to a preceding asterisk). I've also made it a little less anecdotal in tone. // I'd distinguish between 'I saw her go home' and 'I saw her going home', the first meaning 'I saw her leave work (say)' and the second 'I noticed / met her as she was (or as I was!) on her/my way home.'

Answer (score -1):

I would  like to  give  an oft  repeated  example  to  make  the  difference clear.

> **I saw her  crossing the  road**
>
> **I saw  her  cross the  road**

I  saw  her  crossing  the  road  means I  saw  her  when  she  was  crossing  the  road( I saw  her  when she  was  crossing  at  a  point  on the  road)

I saw  her  cross  the  road  means  I  saw  her  crossing  the road  from one  side  to  the  other( the  entire  activity)

Here  is  a  link  which  shows  the  difference.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-%E2%80%9CI-saw-him-cross-the-road%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9CI-saw-him-crossing-the-road%E2%80%9D